# C# - await Task.Delay() function cannot be called

Tags: c#, asynchronous

it seems that **await Task.Delay()** function cannot be called in my function.

I already put **async** in my function name. 
Visual Studio won't recognize the  function. Here is my code

```
private async void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Debug.Write("HI");
        imageBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;

        if (load_qr == false)
        {
            grabber.Dispose();
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
            imageBox2.Image = null;
            button1.Enabled = true;

            load_qr = true;
        }

        //
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
        FinalFrame.VideoResolution = FinalFrame.VideoCapabilities[3];
        FinalFrame.Start();
        button4.Enabled = false;

        // delay

        await Task.Delay(1000); // Visual studio won't recognize this.

        timer1.Start();
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

What's wrong? Am I missing a library? Thank you :)

Comment: You need to be using .net 4.5 or later , or make sure you have `using System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks wont recognize, I think my .net is outdated.

Comment: "won't recognize this", does it give an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

[Task.Delay Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a task that completes after a time delay.

This is only available when using .Net 4.5 or later,
if you are, then make sure you have `using System.Threading.Tasks`

To change the target framework version

`RightClick -> Project -> Properties -> Application Target framework`

Comment: this works! Thank you. I've been using the outdated .Net framework afterall :)